# SSL certificate isn't from a trusted authority in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, qlikview, qliksense

I have Qlik sense and Node.js installed on the same server.

Below is the piece of code i am using in Node.js for validating SSL.

```
     var options = {
        pfx: fs.readFileSync('ABCDEFGH.pfx'),
        passphrase: '******'
     }

    https.createServer(options, app).listen(4011,function() {
        console.log('Https Server listening on port', this.address().port);
     })
```

Qlik Sense hub is working fine when i installed this certificate in that but every time when i assess any service with port 4011(i.e Node.js) it gives below warning in mobile browser or web view.

```
This certificate isn't from a trusted authority.
```

Please help me in this case.

Comment: buy or use a certificate free from http://www.alleft.com/sysadmin/how-to-get-a-free-and-valid-ssl-certificate/

Comment: I am working with a reputed MNC and we have standard paid certificate. Thanks for your help @headmax.